# Gradle file is not running tests

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, junit

I am trying to run my junit tests through gradle file but build gets successful but does not run any tests. This is how my gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

// Creating a new sourceSet because you should move your integration tests to a separate directory.
sourceSets {
    test {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/integration-test/java']
         }
            integrationTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/integration-test/java']        
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output 
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}



task integrationTest(type: Test, description: 'Runs the integration tests', group: 'Verification') {
            testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
            classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
          }
```

After running task integrationTest, build runs successfully but it does not run any tests. Does anyone know why?

Comment: You need to define a `integration-test` [source set](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what exactly you want to do: separate your integration tests of fully move test classes to other folder but I think you need to include the dependencies of test configuration like this:

```
configurations {
    integrationCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
```

For example integration test configuration:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
    }
    integration {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/integration/java']
        resources.srcDir 'src/integration/resources'
        compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task integration(type: Test, group: 'Verification') {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
}
```

In case if you just want to move your tests in other folder(`src/integration-test/java`) and run them with `test` task you can use the following configuration:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/integration-test/java']
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @alex thanks for your answer. Can you look at my updated answer

Comment: @Gaurav Are you sure about that integrationTest sources located in 'src/test/resources' maybe you need to change from `java.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']` to `java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']`...

Comment: i changed it to resources.srcDirs, still tests not running

Comment: no no, it should be `java.srcDirs` but value of this variable need to match to path of folder where your sources are located

Comment: you have one java.srcDirs under test{} and one under integrationTest{}. I have my tests under src/integration-test/java folder so what i am supposed to put and where?

Comment: @Gaurav please take a look on second example from my answer